# How to modify a sheet column regarding another sheet column?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have 2 excel sheets (Sheet1 and Sheet2).

In sheet1 I have a table, I want to modify the table regarding to the second sheet as shown in the image such that the column in table of sheet1 (column called needed) looksup values in sheet2 and if id(1) is found in colmn of id in sheet2 then the cell of this id should get the value that corresponds to the same id in sheet 2.

That is what I basically want, but I can't figure out how to do that in excel

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On `Sheet1` in cell `D2` enter the following formula:

```
=VLOOKUP(A2;Sheet2!$A$2:$D$5;4;FALSE)
```

Note that you might need to change the semicolons `;` to regular commas `,` depending on your version of Excel. Then just copy that cell down the entire column of the table.

Comment: Thanks, this did the job!